# Why are my physics different in the editor and deployment at same framerate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics-engine

So I'm making a 2D tile map test project, and it runs perfectly* in the editor, but once I get it to a windows .exe it runs like crap for no reason**. I didn't touch one character of code, and the deployment settings are default, so I have no idea whats going on. Can anyone give me any ideas?

*You can move about and jump on the level ground and slopes without getting stuck at all

**You get stuck on every tiles corner, and can't go up slopes at all.

Test case - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28109593/unity/MapTest2D.zip

Comment: Questions should be answerable from the information presented directly in your question. As such it's completely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think so at all. 1) My physics are different in and outside the editor. Why? 2) They both have the same frame rate. 3) inside the editor my physics work correctly, but outside it my moving object gets stuck on corners/slopes 4) Here is a test case. Notice the question in (1) and the supporting information in (2 and 3) and finally a test case in (4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it seems (and it is logic) that the Unity engine is faster as standalone than in the editor (of course when you don't have to run all the editor around, and i dont even speak about the profiler...) so knowing that :

Physics will be able to happen more often and it will make more precise calculations, so small details which are not spotted in Editor will be in the build version like small tile differences, and also forces may be applied more accurately and/or more often which could prevent slopes limits to work proerly...

That's not all though you should take a look at your project properties, in player and check if you are running the Editor in Standalone mode and if your selected quality setting is the same.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much. This is the first actual answer to this question I've gotten in the 9 hours I've been looking for people to help me with it. I will accept this as an answer ASAP. Now I can finally start figuring out this error! :D

Comment: So the error was actually that you need to set Sprites to Advanced - Read/Write enabled to get the Polygoncollider2D's to work properly in Stand Alone.

I have a few minor questions if you, or anyone else, would be willing to answer them. 1) Is there a way to set the default settings to advanced - read/write enabled so I don't have to do it for each tile I import? 

2) is there a way I could see the Colliders in stand alone, so I'd know if something like this happens again?

Anyway thank you so much. your answer set me on the right path. :D

Comment: I am not sure there is a built in function to enable defaut import behavior, but you could make an Editor Extension for that, and to see the colliders in Standalone mode i believe you will also need to create a script